# Unable to set WriteTimeout on reactor-netty version 0.9.10

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have written a Reactive API using Spring WebFlux version **2.3.0.RELEASE** having **reactor-netty version 0.9.10**. As part of the API's SLA, I want to timeout the request if the Server takes more than the stipulated configured WriteTimeout.

Sharing the code snipped below where I have implemented a customizer for NettyReactiveWebServerFactory.

```
@Bean
  public WebServerFactoryCustomizer serverFactoryCustomizer() {
    return new NettyTimeoutCustomizer();
  }

  class NettyTimeoutCustomizer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
      int connectionTimeout = 1000;
      int writeTimeout = 1;
          factory.addServerCustomizers(server -> server.tcpConfiguration(tcp ->
              tcp.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
                  .doOnConnection(connection ->
                      connection.addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(writeTimeout)))));
    }
  }
```

In spite of the Customizer, the WriteTimeout is Not Working for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a `WebServerFactoryCustomizer` bean, **create a bean of `NettyReactiveWebServerFactory` to override Spring's auto-configuration.**

```
  @Bean
  public NettyReactiveWebServerFactory nettyReactiveWebServerFactory() {
    NettyReactiveWebServerFactory webServerFactory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
    webServerFactory.addServerCustomizers(new MyCustomizer());
    return webServerFactory;
  }
```

Now the `MyCustomizer` will look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {

  @Override
  public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
    return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(tcpServer -> tcpServer.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 1000)
        .bootstrap(serverBootstrap -> serverBootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
          @Override
          protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
            channel.pipeline().addLast("writeTimeoutHandler", new WriteTimeoutHandler(1));
          }
        }))
    );
  }
}
```

This is the way suggested in the [official API doc](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/WriteTimeoutHandler.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Abhinaba Chakraborty but it is still not working.

Comment: @Abhinandan Probably there is some configuration missing. Please show more code/ give link to your repo. You can also try upgrading the dependency versions.

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty why did you suggest using `bootstrap` method instead of `doOnConnected`? Please note that `bootstrap` method is deprecated and will be removed in 1.0.0. version.

Comment: @Abhinandan When you use `connection.addHandlerLast` there should be a message like this in the logs.
`Added decoder [writeTimeoutHandler] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline:`